# Gmail API список писем

Tags: javascript, gmail

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages
Есть у него метод list, который

Response
If successful, this method returns a response body with the following structure:

```
{
"messages": [
users.messages Resource
],
"nextPageToken": string,
"resultSizeEstimate": unsigned integer
}
```

А мне он возвращает кучу айдишников и всё, а не всё тело письма, в доке написано  users.messages Resource 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Еще там есть метод get, который возвращает полностью весь емейл целиком, но только для конкретного айдишника. 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get
Я хочу, чтобы у меня отображался на странице список моих емейлов и чтобы я могла добавить поиск. 
Неужели мне для этого надо выдирать айдишнкики в какой-нибудь массив с одного запроса, а потом слать сотни/тысячи запросов к серверу?
Это же не может быть правдой.

Comment: А там разве нет API для поиска? У метода [list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) есть параметр `q`, который вы можете использовать для поиска

Comment: "Это же не может быть правдой". Сожалею, но это правда. Потому что она указана в документации явным образом: "Note that each message resource contains only an id and a threadId. Additional message details can be fetched using the messages.get method."